# Stats- Finding percentages between two scores

Tags: statistics

I dont know how to start the problem. can someone help me start it? step by step?

1. A teacher wants to know what percentage of her 5th grade students is reading one grade level above, and one grade level below the norm. The mean grade level equivalent on a reading test for a 5th grade class is 5.5 and the standard deviation is 1.5. What percentage of students are reading at a grade level between 4.5 (one level below) and 6.5 (one level above)?
2. In a further study, the same teacher wants to know what percentage of her students are reading between 8 and 10 books per month because the administration feels that amount is above average at this age. The mean number of books read in her class is 7 per month with a standard deviation of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming normal distribution for both exercises.

Here is an explanation for the first exercise:

$\mu =5.5$ and $\sigma=1.5$, hence

$z(4.5)=(4.5-5.5)/1.5=-2/3$ and $z(6.5)=(6.5-5.5)/1.5=2/3$.

$P[z(4.5) \leq z \leq z(6.5)]=\Phi(2/3)-\Phi(-2/3),$

in which $\Phi(z)$ is the cumulative normal distribution.

Can you complete the second task?